# How do I exclude `.` and `..` from a directory listing

Tags: c, directory

I am reading the current directory and printing it out using

```
printf("%s\n", file->d_name);
```

but it also prints out "." and ".." files. How can I exclude them?

Comment: Printing file names with `%d`?  Good luck with that...

Comment: Simply put a check using `strcmp`. `if(strcmp(file->name, "..")==0)` then don't print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put a check using `strcmp`.

For example:

`if(strcmp(file->name,"..")==0)`

then don't print the file name.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way:  just make sure the file name isn't `"."` or `".."` before you display it.  :P

```
if (strcmp(file->d_name, ".") && strcmp(file->d_name, "..")) {
    printf("%s\n", file->d_name);
}
```